# Why WSO2 API Manager gives Hostname verification failed while getting the token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have one WSO2 Identity server running on docker container and My API-Manager is configured to use it as key manager. API Manager is also running on docker.

When Iam Trying to get a token in Postman, I call this `https://myhost.com:8243/token?grant_type=client_credentials` with base64 encoded "client_id:secret" it gives me this exception:

```
[2021-04-27 17:13:21,704] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : is.com javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : is.com
```

Also the [apim.key_manager] is configured like this:

```
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://is.com:9442/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
type = "WSO2-IS"
```

"is.com" is the domain for my identity server container.

I dont know why is this happening and HostNameVerification is disabled in apim.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you haven't disabled hostname verification in Synapse level. This can be done using the following config in the deployment.toml

```
[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"
```

The recommended approach is to use the correct hostname. For this, you can use a DNS entry.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Dear @Pubci I have similar error, but I am using Keycloak server to supply OAuth tokens.
I used this option to disable hostname verification and I could see that it is reflected in axis2.xml as well.
However, I still get the Hostname verification failed error when trying to get keys.
I am using API Manager version 4.0.0 
Any pointers to check would be extremely helpful. Thank you